# Decode input data in bigquery on polygon

Tags: blockchain, polygon, query

I have a problem in developing a program to decode the **input data** of transactions created by a **smart contract** on the **polygon blockchain**.

#### The smart contract:

https://polygonscan.com/address/0xb6041EAe62C4591458AF480679c6A497EDA6CfcD#code

[image: encode input data]
[image: decode input data]

#### Tx:

https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x1130e3f485353dc9803abf6c741cb495a915a5c764fdbeee9fd7288d79a310eb

#### The function of the smart contract for which I want to decode the input data is:

`function createPack(uint8 packType, bytes memory signature)`

The steps are the following :
1a- Extraction of the data from the google dataset : `public-data-finance.crypto_polygon.transactions`
1b- Decoding in the query in the input_data field
2- Storage of the decoded data in the database

For steps 1a and 1b, I used this source on github : [Gitub blockchain-etl/ethers.js-bigquery](https://github.com/blockchain-etl/ethers.js-bigquery)

I adapted the BigQuery query as follows:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  DECODE_CREATEPACK(data STRING)
  RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
  LANGUAGE js AS """
    var CTA_CREATEPACK = {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "packType",
          "type": "uint8"
        },
        {
          "name": "signature",
          "type": "bytes"
        }
      ],
      "name": "createPack",
      "outputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "payable",
      "type": "function"
    };

    var interface_instance = new ethers.utils.Interface([CTA_CREATEPACK]);
    
    --You might need to wrap with try-catch here as transaction input is user provided data and might not follow abi. 
    var parsedTransaction = interface_instance.parseTransaction({data: data});

    return parsedTransaction.args;
"""
OPTIONS
  ( library="gs://blockchain-etl-bigquery/ethers.js" );
SELECT
  `hash`, DECODE_CREATEPACK(input) AS decoded_input
FROM
  `public-data-finance.crypto_polygon.transactions`
WHERE
  STARTS_WITH(input, "0x48b70391") -- 4byte sighash for createPack(uint8 packType, bytes signature) method
  AND to_address = "0xb6041eae62c4591458af480679c6a497eda6cfcd"
LIMIT 100;
```

When running the query, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at DECODE_CREATEPACK(STRING) line 21, columns 10-15
```

As it seems that my problem comes from the ABI, I compiled the smart contract code on REMIX to get the ABI.
However, I don't have the ABI of the "Contract" functions

```
contract PremiumPack is ERC1155, Ownable, AccessControl, ReentrancyGuard { ... }
```

My solidity skills are very limited so I am stuck on the tracks to solve my problem.

Do any of you have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

The BigQuery data leaves a lot to be desired, which is part of the reason I made [Luabase](https://luabase.com/). Luabase has direct SQL access and already full decodes any contract with verified ABI's. Let me know if you run into any data missing and we can get it added.